# How to fill a numpy arrays nan values with the means of their columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I convert part of a pandas dataframe to a numpy array and I want to fill it's values with the mean of the columns, similarily to how I would do the following in pandas:

```
df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace = True)
```

The only way I have been able to do it so far is iterate over the columns.
Is there another way?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.take`:

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan, 2, 6], 'B': [5, np.nan, 8, 2]})

m = df.to_numpy()
print(m)

# Output
array([[ 1.,  5.],
       [nan, nan],
       [ 2.,  8.],
       [ 6.,  2.]])
```

```
mean = np.nanmean(m, axis=0)
idx = np.where(np.isnan(m))
m[idx] = np.take(mean, idx[1])
print(m)

# Output
array([[1., 5.],
       [3., 5.],
       [2., 8.],
       [6., 2.]])
```

Comment: Apologies, I was probably unclear. I know how to do this with a dataframe, I want to do the equivalent to a numpy array.

Comment: Ah, you edited just after I posted the above comment, thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to read that and sorry for the wrong answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.where` like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 1, np.nan, 6], 'B': [4, np.nan, 8, np.nan]})

a = df.to_numpy()
print(a)
# [[ 2.  4.]
#  [ 1. nan]
#  [nan  8.]
#  [ 6. nan]]

a = np.where(np.isnan(a), np.nanmean(a, axis=0), a) 
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[2. 4.]
 [1. 6.]
 [3. 8.]
 [6. 6.]]
```

Comment: Oh nice, thank you! that's a very elegant solution!

Comment: @Olli welcome dude